# My PyPI distribution is only installing dist

Tags: pypi

I have a package named `pyuvm`.  The source files are in `pyuvm/pyuvm`

When I build it and send it up to `pypi.org` I don't see any errors, and when I install it I don't see any errors, but there is no `pyuvm` directory in `site-packages` there is a `pyuvm-2.0a3.dist-info` file.

I've got this `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = pyuvm
version = 2.0a3
author = Ray Salemi
author_email = ray@raysalemi.com
description = Python implementation of the Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) using cocotb
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/pyuvm/pyuvm
project_urls=
   Bug Tracker=https://github.com/pyuvm/pyuvm/issues
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
[options]

packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

install_requires =
 cocotb >= 1.5.2

[options.packages.find]
where = pyuvm
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by switching back to `setup.py`

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="pyuvm",
    version="2.0a8",
    author="Ray Salemi",
    author_email="ray@raysalemi.com",
    description="A Python implementation of the UVM using cocotb",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pyuvm/pyuvm",
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/pyuvm/pyuvm/issues",
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Electronic Design Automation (EDA)",
    ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    install_requires="cocotb>=1.5.2",
)
```

The key was removing the `package_dir` argument from setup completely and setting `find_packages` to have no argument.